# ImageButton не работает

Tags: android, android-button

Я создаю кнопку Button:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/img_btn_close"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/baseline_close_black_18dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
```

устанавливаю для неё слушатель нажатий:

```
Button btnClose = findViewById(R.id.img_btn_close);
        btnClose.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            finish();
        });
```

и всё отлично работает - при нажатии на кнопку окно закрывается. Однако я хочу заменить `Button` на `ImageButton`. Я меняю тег `<Button>` на  `<ImageButton>`, в коде заменяю строку

```
Button btnClose = findViewById(R.id.img_btn_close);
```

на

```
ImageButton btnClose = findViewById(R.id.img_btn_close);
```

однако после этого кнопка вообще не реагирует на нажатия. Также я меняла в макете

```
android:background="@drawable/baseline_close_black_18dp"
```

на

```
android:src="@drawable/baseline_close_black_18dp"
```

однако это тоже не помогло - кнопка по-прежнему не реагирует на нажатия. В чём может быть причина проблемы?

**UPD**

Оказалось, что в макете под кнопкой был `RecyclerView`, который перекрывал кнопку:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/img_btn_close"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:padding="@dimen/side_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/baseline_close_white_18dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/side_margin"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/side_margin"
    android:contentDescription="@string/btn_close_description"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
     />

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/btn_visit_collection" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_visit_collection"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/btn_visit_collection"
    android:textSize="@dimen/btn_text_size"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:padding="@dimen/side_margin"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/side_margin"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/side_margin"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/recycler_view"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
```

После того, как я установила `RecyclerView` ниже `ImageButton`:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/img_btn_close"
    ...
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/recycler_view" />

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    ...
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/btn_visit_collection" />
```

кнопка стала кликабельной. Осталось непонятным только то, каким образом при том же неправильном макете (когда `RecyclerView` перекрывал кнопку), работала обычная `Button`?..

Comment: А `InstantRun` у вас отключён? Пробовали `clean` проекту делать?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, clean делала, запускаю на реальном устройстве, не на эмуляторе - вроде же тогда InstantRun не должен влиять?

Comment: Вроде, он независимо от девайс/эмулятор работает.

Comment: 1) Попробуйте добавить `android:clickable="true"`. 2) Оно вообще не кликается или кликается, но в другой области экрана, например?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, отключила InstantRun, не помогло(

Comment: @Suvitruf, добавляла, +добавляла focusable, но тоже не помогло( Не видно, чтобы вообще кликалось

Comment: @Ksenia оно не вложено в плавающие контейнеры? У меня как-то раз была похожая проблема с некликабельностью. Как ни смешно, но пересоздание проекта с нуля и копирование из старого решило проблему.

Comment: @Suvitruf, а что значит " плавающие контейнеры", это какие контейнеры?)
Вообще ImageButton у меня вложена только в один контейнер, корневой -  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

Comment: @Ksenia я про `FlowLayout`'ы и т.п. (:

Comment: Попробуйте поменять `android:src` на `app:src`

Comment: Нашла причину - обновила вопрос)

Comment: Возможно в Button были прописаны настройки запрешающие перекрывать себя или ч.т.т.